# Argument labels '(contentsOfURL:, error:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift

code snippet:

[image]

Hello all, 
     I have been looking this question up for about two days now and none of the fixes on the websites, including this one, have been working. When I try to run my code this error pops up and I cannot figure out why. I have heard things from "change your team under the general section" to "it's not finding your mp3 url correctly" and I just started with swift and xcode so I have absolutely no clue.

Thanks,
Austin

Comment: post code and error log here, not image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are trying copy paste this code with lower version of Swift, the error is handled with `throws` now, so change it to:

```
 do {
     let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: fileURL)
 } catch {
     print(error)
 }
```

or just `let player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: fileURL)` if you do not wish to handle the error

Comment: Thanks Tj3n! That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Error handling is not done using `Try-Catch` in latest Swift Versions.

Try this:

```
do{
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfUrl: fileURL)
    player.prepareToPlay()
}catch {
    print("file not found")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue but in my case,

I extended a **`struct`** model with the same reserved keyword **`Data`** like

```
struct Data: Decodable {
    let data: Payload
    let msgList: [Messages]
}
```

so on fetching contents of a file using getting this error

[image]

**Solution**

Just rename extended struct name something like

```
struct MyData: Decodable { .. }
```

Hope this will help, Cheers!